# Disable cflag in makefile

Tags: makefile

If a macro is being defined on the compiler, as:

```
cflag += -D name
```

How could I disable this definition?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but you could comment out that line in your `makefile` (`#cflag += ...`), or later in the file set `cflag` to be empty (`cflag=`)...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a flag from `cflag`, you can either:

1. Comment out the line that adds the flag.
2. Reset `cflag` to a known value that excludes the flag.
3. Use `$(subst)` to strip the flag from `cflag`, as follows:

   `cflag := $(subst -D name,,$(cflag)`

Note that you could also do the substitution at the point where `cflag` is referenced.